# Overriding the build configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron

I am working on a react/electron project with webpack for bundling and electron-builder to compile the build. I am trying to override the build configuration after its compiled by providing a custom configuration file in the install directory of the application to override the env variables. I have verified `process.env` updates but the config variables still use the old configuration which was used at the time of compilation. Is there any way this can be achieved?

For example

`const apiKey = process.env.APIKEY`

In this case `process.env.APIKEY` has the updated config but `apiKey` still points to the older key used at the time of compiling the build.

Answer (score 0):

1. First install dotenv - `npm install dotenv`
2. Create an `.env` file in the same folder as `package.json`
3. Then create the environment variables starting with → `REACT_APP_`

   Example of point 3:

   Inside `.env` file → `REACT_APP_URL_PATH=xxxxx`
4. Start your project locally and add some `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_URL_PATH)` 
   just to check.

5.- Do the electron thing.

↓↓↓↓↓ `npm dotenv` ↓↓↓↓↓

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Yes that's what happening i am using dotenv package but I want to override the compiled build configuration too which doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Alien128 If you are asking how can you change it when its alredy BUILT, then i dont know but if you debug without the electron part works?, if so then check that electron config or share it :)

Comment: Yes i want to change it once its already built.